# Which language(s) is Bing and Google written in?

Tags: programming-languages, bing

Which language(s) is Bing and Google written in? I heard Google's back end (the part which does the actual search) was written in C++? How accurate is that? And what about Bing?

Comment: knowledge for knowledge's sake, eh?

Comment: What parts of Google and Bing are you asking about?

Comment: A variety of languages. Pagerank was invented in the late 90's, so C++ is a safe guess for that part of the algorithm. More likely than not, they use several other languages between when you start typing and when you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed in C++.

Google uses [ctemplate](http://code.google.com/p/google-ctemplate/).